# Java: Phone Number filter and allocation to "Elite"

Tags: java, regex, performance, filter, phone-number

Task is to allocate from bulk of numbers (200k total) Elite and Premium ones. Elite means number is very beautiful and expensive, Premium means more-less beautiful.

My solution works, but it is very slow. To process 200k numbers takes about 40 minutes! Problem is that I have to generate thousands of Regex patterns using masks and then process thousands of numbers through thousands of patterns!

Patterns looks like patternX, patternXY, patternAB, patternABC, patternXAB, patternXABC, patternXYZ, patternXYAB, patternXYAB,  for example:

```
super.patternXYZ = "^\\d+XXYYZZ$|^\\d+ZZXYXY$|^\\d+YXXYYZZ..$";
super.patternXYAB = "^\\d+ABXXYY$|^\\d+ABXYXY$";
```

Where all the letters are represent mask of numbers: XXYY mathces 4488 or 9933 (X<>=Y) and AABB matches serial sequences like 3344 or 7788 (A+1=B)

Matching occurs by following:

```
@Override
public Set<String> performCollect() {
    for (String number : numbers) {
        if (isPatternXMatches(number)) {
            result.add(number);
        } else if (isPatternXYMatches(number)) {
            result.add(number);
        } 
        ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

Where Regex patterns are being generated for every single match and match performs:

```
protected boolean isPatternXYZMatches(String number) {
    for (int X = 0; X < 10; X++) {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < 10; Y++) {
            for (int Z = 0; Z < 10; Z++) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternXYZ.replace("X", String.valueOf(X)).replace("Y", String.valueOf(Y)).replace("Z", String.valueOf(Z)));
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(number);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

protected boolean isPatternXYABMatches(String number) {
    for (int X = 0; X < 10; X++) {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < 10; Y++) {
            for (int A = 0, B = 1; B < 10; A++, B++) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternXYAB.replace("A", String.valueOf(A)).replace("B", String.valueOf(B)).replace("X", String.valueOf(X)).replace("Y", String.valueOf(Y)));
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(number);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Question: Does anyone know or could suggest some better and faster solution?

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: What do you generate the regexes from?

Comment: I added sample methods isPatternXYZMatches(), isPatternXYABMatches() where I am generating regexes

Comment: @JuriBogdanov That looks really bad. I mean, really, really bad. You create, compile, evaluate and throw away a 1000 regexes for each number and pattern. That's a crazy amount of needless work. Forget regexes, think like this: you've got a pattern in the form of `XXYYZZ` and let's say the number `112234` (as a string). Now try to write something that reads both the pattern and the number character by character and decides whether the number matches the pattern.

Comment: Thanks bizclop, started thinking about the same thing after posted it. Will try to redo and will see how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced Regex with custom matcher and 200k numbers are now processed during 5 seconds instead of 40 minutes!

```
public Set<String> performCollect() {
    for (String number : numbers) {
        if (isNumberMatches(number)) {
            result.add(number);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

protected boolean isNumberMatches(String number) {
    NumberMatcher nm = new NumberMatcher(number, offset);
    for (NumberPattern pattern : patterns) {
        if (nm.processMatch(pattern)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

...

```
public class NumberPattern {

    private char[] maskChars;
    private Integer weight;

    public NumberPattern(String mask, Integer weight) {
        maskChars = mask.toCharArray();
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public char[] getMaskChars() {
        return maskChars;
    }

    public void setMaskChars(char[] maskChars) {
        this.maskChars = maskChars;
    }

    public Integer getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class NumberMatcher {

    private char[] numberChars;
    private int uniqueChars = 0;

    public NumberMatcher(String number, int offset) {
        numberChars = number.toCharArray();
        List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Character ch : number.substring(offset).toCharArray()) {
            if (!chars.contains(ch)) {
                uniqueChars++;
                chars.add(ch);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean processMatch(NumberPattern pattern) {
        if (pattern.getWeight() < uniqueChars) {
            return false;
        }

        Character X = null;
        Character Y = null;
        Character Z = null;
        Character A = null;
        Character B = null;
        Character C = null;
        Character D = null;

        final char[] patternChars = pattern.getMaskChars();
        int patternIndex = patternChars.length;
        int numberIndex = numberChars.length;

        while (patternIndex > 0) {
            patternIndex--;
            numberIndex--;
            char numberChar = numberChars[numberIndex];
            char patternChar = patternChars[patternIndex];

            switch (patternChar) {
                case 'A':
                    if (A == null) {
                        A = numberChar;
                        B = (char) (A + 1);
                        C = (char) (B + 1);
                        D = (char) (C + 1);
                    } else if (!A.equals(numberChar)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    if (B == null) {
                        B = numberChar;
                        A = (char) (B - 1);
                        C = (char) (B + 1);
                        D = (char) (C + 1);
                    } else if (!B.equals(numberChar)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    if (C == null) {
                        C = numberChar;
                        B = (char) (C - 1);
                        A = (char) (B - 1);
                        D = (char) (C + 1);
                    } else if (!C.equals(numberChar)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    if (D == null) {
                        D = numberChar;
                        C = (char) (D - 1);
                        B = (char) (C - 1);
                        A = (char) (B - 1);
                    } else if (!D.equals(numberChar)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'X':
                    if (X == null) {
                        X = numberChar;
                    } else if (!X.equals(numberChar)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Y':
                    if (Y == null) {
                        Y = numberChar;
                    } else if (!Y.equals(numberChar)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Z':
                    if (Z == null) {
                        Z = numberChar;
                    } else if (!Z.equals(numberChar)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case '.':
                    break;
                case '0':
                    if (numberChar != '0') {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```